# Where is this tab "tab=interesting" actually present?

Tags: support, user-interface, hyperlinks, interesting-page

I kind of stumbled on the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting

But could not find the link in the page, that has this url. Where is this link actually available at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the homepage, the same thing as https://stackoverflow.com/

[image: SO homepage interesting tab]

When you switch between tabs on the homepage (`featured`, `hot`, `new`, etc.) then back to that first tab it uses the `?tab=interesting` query string to indicate you've just switched back to the default tab again.

The homepage tab choice is stored in a cookie for the next time you come visit the homepage; it'll show last tab you choose.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.